# DateTime Precision / Accuracy

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, precision

I'd like to represent dates with different precisions (accuracies). Ideally I can use the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) datatype to store the date information though it doesn't come with a precision setting. For example, I have the date "1/1/2015", but depending on its precision it will be understood to be:

- an exact date: 1 JAN 2015
- month and year only: JAN 2015
- year only: 2015

The precision is needed for both UI formatting as well as business logic hence I don't like to use the .NET out of the box formatting options that come with [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) or others - they have a different purpose.

Consequently, there is my own solution that is essentially an enumeration ...

```
public enum DateTimePrecision
{
    DayMonthYear = 0,
    MonthYear,
    Year,
    ...
}
```

... that goes with the date (struct or class) ...

```
public class MySuperDupaAwesomeDateTime
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTimePrecision Precision { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, I could build my own custom *DateTime* of course.

Anyway, this is like re-inventing something that feels so common and must be out there already. Can anybody think of an improvement of the above approach or knows about a .NET Framework feature? I am not looking for a library or anything, but a solution that comes straight out of .NET.

Comment: Seems fine. Asking for a library is offtopic, but I am pretty sure there's nothing in the .NET framework.

Comment: From our very own Jon Skeet: http://nodatime.org/

Comment: @RonBeyer does nodatime offer this variable accuracy functionality?

Comment: @Blorgbeard it looks like it comes close, see http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalDate.htm you can try tagging Jon to get his much better opinion.

Comment: Tagging people who aren't involved in the question (thankfully) does not notify them.

Comment: Ahh, well then that explains that :)

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you! Would you please lead me to more specific sub-page for _Noda Time_ which explains how date accuracy works? LocalDate is a different concept and doesn't let me set a month only or year only date.

Comment: I would start another question specifically for NodaTime (use it in a tag) so that somebody who knows about it like Jon may see it, I'm by far not an expert in NodaTime unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

DateTime has some identifiers for `Month` and `Year` that are integers. Use them and format it into a `String`.

If you need more accuracy than just a day, `DateTime` also has other identifiers for `Second`s, `Minute`s, `Hour`s, `Millisecond`s... check the attributes for yourself!

After you get the integer values for them, you can even start to do calculations for getting elapsed time for something to complete (by getting a `DateTime` and setting it for `Now` when you start and getting another `DateTime` and setting that for `Now` when it's over, then use the `name of second object.Subtract( name of the first object )`, or `.Add()`)!

Comment: Not sure how this answers my question. If you store a "1/1/2015" in a `DateTime` how does your suggestion tell me whether I'd like to store the year only - or the full date?

Comment: You can't with `DateTime`, but you can get just the year as an object or the full date.

Comment: The reasoning is, the `DateTime` object represents a date and time. You can't set its accuracy, but you can get specific values out of it and add them to a string.

Comment: Thanks. Agreed. However, I am looking for an accuracy setting which is not provided by `DateTime` hence my question.

Comment: I just re-read the question. I think Microsoft should make an accuracy setting, but, until then, you'll have to make your own custom DateTime.

Comment: That would be awesome indeed. Thanks!